# setting 'in' but not 'out' in tikz 'to' path

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I use code like this in tikz it works how I expect:

```
\draw (0,1) to[out=0, in=180] (1,0);
```

[image]

However, if I set `in` but not `out` then something weird happens:

```
\draw (0,1) to[in=180] (1,0);
```

[image]

What I was expecting was that the line would start out heading towards the target node and then bend so that it ends up horizontal at the end, something like one of the curves below:

[image]

However, instead the curve starts out travelling upwards at about a 45 degree angle, which seems kind of illogical.

So the questions are, first what's going on here, and secondly is there a way to achieve what I wanted?

This is for a small library I'm developing, so if there's a solution I'd need it to work and look reasonable for any positions of the end-points, without any manual fine-tuning. Of the two curves I drew above, the one on the left would look a lot better than the other.

Apologies if this is described in some obvious place - it turns out to be quite hard to search for terms like 'in', 'out' and 'to'.

Here is the full MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) to[out=0, in=180] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) to[in=180] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `[out=<>,in=<>]` is on the Ti*k*Z level. You may read the Ti*k*Z/PGF manual and find the implementation of this command. That way, you would know exactly what is going on, on the PGF level, and then maybe find a way to hack the command.

Comment: My guess is that there is a default out angle. Do you get the same out angle irrespective of where the target node is? Do you really want the out direction to be directly towards the target node as that will still mean it has an S shape since it will care slightly away before coming back to it. You could try a hobby cave with only an in angle.

Comment: If you search for `out=` in the manual, then you'll quickly find an example where it's used. You can then click on `out` to go to the description of the key (which is in chapter 74 about the `topaths` library). It says there that both `in` and `out` has "no default" though ...

Comment: @AndrewStacey the ideal thing would be a curve that looks like the left-most of the two I drew, i.e. one that intelligently avoids making the 'S' shape you mention. However, I imagine the 'S' shaped version could be implemented more easily and it would be acceptable for me if a smarter alternative isn't available. What's a hobby cave?

Comment: Think Andrew meant "Hobby curve".

Comment: @SebGlav thank you, that must be it - I hadn't heard that term before. (There is a `hobby` tikz package, and indeed it seems able to do what I want, though it seems it has a restriction that you can only draw Hobby curves between explicitly specified coordinates, not between nodes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels like you want to define a path that depends only on the `in` angle.  Since, in TikZ, curved paths are cubic béziers, specifying only the in angle isn't enough information.  So we need to figure out another control point to give a reasonable curve.  The following code does this in the following way.  We start by defining the *second* control point at the specified angle from the end point and at a distance of one third of the separation between the starting and ending points.  Then we define the first control point so that it means that the path leaves the start point in the direction of the second control point (and again at a distance of a third of the separation - thirds work well with cubic béziers).

Finally, this is put together into a `to` path to make it easy to use.  It does use the `calc` library to make the calculations easier but that could be removed with a bit more code.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609102/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  only in/.style={
  to path={
  let
  \p1 = ($ (\tikztotarget) - (\tikztostart) $)
  in
   .. controls 
  ($(\tikztostart)!{veclen(\x1,\y1)/3}!($(\tikztotarget)+(#1:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/3})$)$)
  and
  ($(\tikztotarget)+(#1:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/3})$)
  .. (\tikztotarget)
  }
  }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) to[only in=180] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: curved path with only in angle specified]

(The poor resolution is due to screenshotting a zoomed in webpage.)

The factor of 1/3 could be customised using a key similar to the `looseness` key on usual `to` paths.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach modifies the codebase as lightly as possible.

It lets you use `in looseness` along with `in`,
and the good old computation is used to compute the second control point.
Then, it uses `out looseness` to define the first control point as follows

```
($ the starting point ! out looseness ! the second control point $)
```

You can swap `out`/`from`/`start` with `in`/`to`/`end`/`target`
to define `only out`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    only in/.code={%
        \tikzset{in=#1}%
        \def\tikz@to@start@compute@looseness{%
            \def\tikz@computed@start{($%
                (\tikztostart)% the starting point
                !\tikz@to@out@looseness!% you choose the looseness
                \tikz@computed@end% second control point (TikZ will compute it)
            $)}%
        }%
        \let\tikz@to@start@compute=\tikz@to@start@compute@looseness
        % ^ There is an \ifx that tests if \...@compute
        % ^ is one of the predefined ones.
        % ^ Since we redefine \...@looseness, this \ifx is no longer true.
        % ^ I added a \let to honor that \ifx and make the hack works
    }
}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \foreach\A in{1,2,3,4}{
        \foreach\B in{1,2,3,4}{
            \draw(\A*3,\B*3)
                to[only in=180,out looseness=\A/4,in looseness=\B/2]
                +(2.5,-2.5);
        }
    }
}
\tikz{
    \foreach\A in{1,2,3,4}{
        \foreach\B in{1,2,3,4}{
            \draw(\A*3,\B*3)node(S){START}+(2.5,-2.5)node(T){TARGET}
                (S)to[only in=180,out looseness=\A/4,in looseness=\B/2](T)
            ;
        }
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]