# Setting tikz path options with a newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

**Note:** I've just realised an answer to this question might not help me - I'd forgotten about the issue in [setting 'in' but not 'out' in tikz 'to' path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609102/setting-in-but-not-out-in-tikz-to-path) , which kind of makes it moot - I'll probably have to consider each combination separately anyway. An answer to the general question of "how can you expand `\newcommand` inside a TikZ path's options" might still be helpful for someone else, though.

I would like to make a command that outputs the options for a tikz path. In the following MWE, the `\pathoptions` macro always outputs `out=0`, but in my real code its output will vary depending on user input. The following code fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pathoptions}{
    out=0
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[\pathoptions] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
./tikz_path_options.tex:12: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz
/ out=0 ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

so it seems like it's seeing "out=0" as the name of the key, instead of setting the key "out" to the value "0". How can I resolve this?

---

It's possible this is an XY problem, so I'll preemptively say what I'm trying to achieve. The idea is that sometimes the `\pathoptions` macro will output `out=0`, sometimes `in=180`, sometimes both and sometimes neither.

So the desired effect is that depending on user input, the path might or might not have fixed orientations for either or both of its end points. This  is what I'm really trying to achieve, and if there's another way to get this result I'm happy to hear it.

However, I'd prefer to avoid having to consider each of the four combinations individually (`[out=0,in=180]`, `[out=0]`, `[in=180]` and `[]`), since if I add other keys the number of combinations will multiply exponentially.

Comment: `style/.expand once=\pathoptions`. But, yes, it seems proper PGFkeys styles would be the better way to go. Maybe you can explain better what you need.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel in case it helps: the user will make a "connection" from a node/coordinate to another node/coordinate. To do this they call a command that draws a path. The style of the path will depend on the names of the nodes that the path is connected to. If you connect to a node whose name contains the string "out", then that end of the path will have an angle of 180. If the name contains the string "in", then that end of the path will have an angle of 0. If neither, then no specified angle. Hence the path options need to be generated programmatically, using `xstring`'s `\IfSubStr` command.

Comment: You can do this inside TikZ/PGFkeys, too.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that would be great to know about. I've made an answer based on your first comment - if you care about points then feel free to post your own and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the `expand once` solution works, but not if the `\pathoptions` command takes an argument. In that case it gives an error "Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeyscurrentkey." Do you know how to resolve that?

Comment: What ever `\pathoptions` does, it needs to be *expandable* so that PGFkeys will only see keys and values. Otherwise use `check my arguments={#1}{#2}` defined as `check my arguments/.code 2 args={<do stuff and then>\pgfkeysalso{out=180}<or other stuff and then>\tikzset{in=0}}`. Or `check my argments/.style 2 args={/utils/exec=<stuff>,other styles}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Hadn't encountered the `style` key - that's astonishingly useful to know about!  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure to have understood your problem, but why don't you use TikZ styles?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  styleA/.style={
    out=0,in=180 
    },
  styleB/.style={
    out=0 
    },
  styleC/.style={
    in=180 
    }
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[styleA] (1,1);
    \draw (0,-1) to[styleB] (1,0);
    \draw (0,-2) to[styleC] (1,-1);
    \draw (0,-3) to[] (1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*
With a parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pathoptions}[1]{\tikzset{mystyle/.style={#1}}}

\begin{document}

\pathoptions{out=0,in=180}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[mystyle] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pathoptions{out=0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[mystyle] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pathoptions{in=180}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[mystyle] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pathoptions{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[mystyle] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution while I only have four possibilities, and I will probably use it. If I were also trying to set other keys depending on user input, this method would require defining 8 or 16 or 32 (etc.) different styles to cover all the combinations - that's what I was trying to get at in the last paragraph of my question. Maybe I'll just cross that bridge when I come to it, though.

Comment: @N.Virgo See my edit (even if I think others better guess your question).

Answer (score 3):

I'll show two solutions:

1. The first one uses only TikZ/PGFkeys with the help of

   - the `/utils/if={<cond>}{<true kv>}{<false kv>}` key that tests for `<cond>` and applies either `<true kv>` or `<false kv>` and
   - a PGFmath function called `instr("<sub>","<text>")` that returns `1` (true) when `<sub>` is in `<text>`, otherwise `0` (false).
2. The second solution uses a `check outin xstring={<start>}{<target>}` that uses `xstring`'s `\IfSubStr` and applies the needed styles via `\pgfkeysalso`.

Inside options of `to`, you can access the start and target of the path as `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget` which is what I'm using in the first solution. This does not work with an `edge` which is why `check outin xstring` takes two arguments.

Obviously, the style of first solution could also be defined as

```
check outin/.style 2 args={
  /utils/if={instr("out","#1")}{check@out@sta},
  /utils/if={instr("in","#1")}{check@in@sta},
  /utils/if={instr("out","#2")}{check@out@tar},
  /utils/if={instr("in","#2")}{check@in@tar}
}
```

and be used as `[check outin={<start node>}{<target node>}]`.

Both solutions check for both given coordinates if they contain `out` *and* if they contain `in` and applies the `check@[in|out]@[sta|tar]` styles.

If name contains `in` the connections will be made to the west (`180`), if `out` then east (`0`). If you name a node `inandout`, the `in` will win since the check for `in` is always last. This does not check whether you have actually used node names.

Note, that only setting one of `out` or `in`, TikZ will draw a curved line with the default value of `in = 135` or `out = 45`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\let\IFX\pgfutil@ifx
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{instr}{2}{%
  \pgfutil@in@{#1}{#2}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@\def\pgfmathresult{1}\else\def\pgfmathresult{0}\fi}
\pgfkeys{/utils/if/.code n args={3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  check@out@sta/.style={out=  0},
  check@in@sta/.style ={out=180},
  check@out@tar/.style={in =  0},
  check@in@tar/.style ={in =180},
  check outin/.style={
    /utils/if={instr("out","\tikztostart")}{check@out@sta},
    /utils/if={instr("in","\tikztostart")}{check@in@sta},
    /utils/if={instr("out","\tikztotarget")}{check@out@tar},
    /utils/if={instr("in","\tikztotarget")}{check@in@tar}},
  check outin xstring/.code 2 args={% #1 = start, #2 = target
    \IfSubStr{#1}{out}{\pgfkeysalso{solid,check@out@sta}}{}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{in} {\pgfkeysalso{solid,check@in@sta}} {}%
    \IfSubStr{#2}{out}{\pgfkeysalso{solid,check@out@tar}}{}%
    \IfSubStr{#2}{in} {\pgfkeysalso{solid,check@in@tar}} {}}}
\newcommand*\doOutIn[3][]{
  \IfStrEq{#2}{#3}{}{
  \path[loosely dotted,#1] (#2) edge[check outin xstring={#2}{#3}] (#3);}}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={nodes=draw,overlay,execute at end picture={
  \useasboundingbox[overlay=false] (nope3.west) -- (nope2.south) --
    ([yshift=5mm]nope1.north) -- ([xshift=5mm]nope4.east);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  n/.style={sloped,above,allow upside down,font=\tiny,draw=none,scale=.5}]
\node (letmein) {in}; \node (checkmeout) at (2,1) {out};
\node (nope1) at (-2, 2) {nope1}; \node (nope2) at (-1,-2) {nope2};
\node (nope3) at (-3, 0) {nope3}; \node (nope4) at (2, -2) {nope4};

\foreach \sta[count=\i] in {letmein, checkmeout, nope1, nope2, nope3, nope4}
  \foreach \tar[count=\j, evaluate={\col=(\i+10*\j)/66*100;}]
    in {letmein, checkmeout, nope1, nope2, nope3, nope4} {\IFX\sta\tar{}{
      \draw[red!\col!blue] (\sta) to[check outin] node[n]{\sta-\tar} (\tar);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \sta[count=\i] in {letmein, checkmeout, nope1, nope2, nope3, nope4}
  \foreach \tar[count=\j, evaluate={\col=(\i+10*\j)/66*100;}]
    in {letmein, checkmeout, nope1, nope2, nope3, nope4} {
    \doOutIn[red!\col!blue]{\sta}{\tar}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by Qrrbrbirlbel, the following works as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pathoptions}{
    out=0
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[style/.expand once=\pathoptions] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work nicely with the `xstring` package that I was hoping to use - the following code fails with the error "Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeyscurrentkey."

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\pathoptions}{
    \IfSubStr{test}{est}{
        out=0
    } {
        in=180
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[style/.expand once=\pathoptions] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `check pathoptions/.style={/utils/exec=\IfSubStr{test}{est}{out=0}{in=180}[\pathoptions],style/.expand once=\pathoptions}` and then `to[check pathoptions]`. Section 3.2 of `xparse` manual.