\IfSubStr inside tikz path style
I don't know whether what I'm trying to do is possible at all, but I really want to make a tikz path style that behaves differently depending on the names of the coordinates it's given.
Here's a minimal non-working example. In this example, which is a much simplified version of my actual code, the path should automatically specify out=0 and in=180 if the start coordinate contains the string east and the target contains the string west.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\tikzset{
    wire/.style={
        \IfSubStr{\tikztostart}{east}{
            \IfSubStr{\tikztotarget}{west}{
                out=0,
                in=180
            } {}
        } {}
    }
}

\begin{document}

% desired behaviour: draw a curved line between the two nodes
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$f$};
    \node[draw] (g) at (2,1) {$g$};
    \draw[wire] (f.east) to (g.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

% desired behaviour: draw a straight line between the two nodes, because the coordinates don't have "east" and "west" as substrings
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$f$};
    \node[draw] (g) at (2,1) {$g$};
    \draw[wire] (f) to (g);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

However, this fails with the error illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeyscurrentkey, so I guess there is an expansion issue of some kind.
So my question is whether there's any way to do the kind of thing I'm trying to do, whether it's by fixing my example or by achieving it another way?
In my actual code there are a bunch of custom anchors with names like in 1/2 and out 4/4, generated by the code from this answer. The goal is to look for the substrings in  and out , so that paths always behave in a certain way depending on what kind of anchor they're connected to.
Here's the desired output from the example.


Why not simply \draw (f) to (g) which would automatically choose the appropriate side of the border?

@JasperHabicht what I want to happen in this example is that \draw[wire] (f) to (g) would draw a straight line, but \draw[wire] (f.east) to (g.west) would draw a curved one, by specifying out=0, in=180. The reason for wanting that is somewhat out of the scope of the question, but I'm developing a tikz library and if I can do this I can make it more convenient to use, because you'll just be able to specify the end points of the path and it will decide how and whether to curve automatically.

I've changed the example and added an image to illustrate that

xstring macros are not expandable as far as I know so you can't use them on a path or as part of a key, certainly not that way. /.code=\IfSubStr{}{}{\tikzset{in=…, out=…}}{…} would work. But for \tikztostart TikZ has converted any coordinate specification that isn't a node with a shape into a x/y coordinate anyway, so you can't even test for the anchor names as that information is lost.

@Qrrbrbirlbel thank you, that jibes with what Jasper Habicht said in his answer. It just means I'll have to give up on doing this in a "tikz native" way and instead have a normal TeX macro. You'll call it like \wire{f.east}{g.west} and then it'll do the test and spit out the appropriate \draw command. This is less elegant than a pure tikz solution would be, but I've tested it and it works.

Your approach can't work, because at the time where you call the style wire, it is not known to TikZ what \tikztostart and \tikztotarget are (these tokens are not even defined at this point), so you can't apply tests here.
Another problem is that \tikztostart (same holds for tikztotarget) never contains f.east, for example, but instead a coordinate value such as 6.5191pt,0.0pt. So, a test for east as substring does not work. It does contain f however, if it refers to a node.
So, what we need to do actually is test whether \tikztostart contains a coordinate (represented as 6.5191pt,0.0pt or the like) or a node name (such as f). This nice answer found a way to do this using an internal PGF command that can be used to distinguish between a node and a coordinate: \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1} (where #1 is the name of the node). We can apply this approach here.
Finally, instead of applying the options in and out we need to make use of more basic commands, because we need to define a custom to path here to do what you want to achieve, and we can't define a to path using to as this would create a loop.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\ifPgfpointOrNode#1#2#3{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{%
        #2%
    }{%
        #3%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    wire/.style={
        to path={
            \pgfextra{
                \ifPgfpointOrNode{\tikztostart}{
                    \def\wireconnection{
                        .. controls ([xshift=1em]\tikztostart) 
                           and ([xshift=-1em]\tikztotarget) .. 
                    }
                }{ 
                    \def\wireconnection{--}
                }
            }
            (\tikztostart) \wireconnection (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

% desired behaviour: draw a curved line between the two nodes
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$f$};
    \node[draw] (g) at (2,1) {$g$};
    \draw[wire] (f.east) to (g.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

% desired behaviour: draw a straight line between the two nodes, because the coordinates don't have "east" and "west" as substrings
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$f$};
    \node[draw] (g) at (2,1) {$g$};
    \draw[wire] (f) to (g);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Or maybe a bit closer to the original defintion:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\ifPgfpointOrNode#1#2#3{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{%
        #2%
    }{%
        #3%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\wiredistance}
\tikzset{
    wire/.style={
        to path={
            \pgfextra{
                \path (\tikztostart);
                \pgfgetlastxy{\wiretempax}{\wiretempay}
                \path (\tikztotarget);
                \pgfgetlastxy{\wiretempbx}{\wiretempby}
                \pgfmathsetlength\wiredistance{
                    sqrt((\wiretempbx-\wiretempax)^2+(\wiretempby-\wiretempay)^2)
                }
                \ifPgfpointOrNode{\tikztostart}{
                    \def\wireconnection{
                        .. controls ([xshift={0.5*\wiredistance}]\tikztostart) and ([xshift={-0.5*\wiredistance}]\tikztotarget) ..  
                    }
                }{ 
                    \def\wireconnection{--}
                }
            }
            (\tikztostart) \wireconnection (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

% desired behaviour: draw a curved line between the two nodes
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$f$};
    \node[draw] (g) at (2,1) {$g$};
    \draw[wire] (f.east) to (g.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

% desired behaviour: draw a straight line between the two nodes, because the coordinates don't have "east" and "west" as substrings
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (f) at (0,0) {$f$};
    \node[draw] (g) at (2,1) {$g$};
    \draw[wire] (f) to (g);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Do I understand right that this will draw the curvy path if the wire is connected to any two named anchors, and only draw the straight line if one of its end points is a node? If so this is workable, but it means I can't implement all the features I hoped. (E.g. I hoped that if you connected an 'out' to an 'out' I could make it specify out=0, in=0, so that the wire makes a u-turn.) But I think from what you said it just won't be possible to do everything I hoped to do, at least not in a 'tikz-native' way like this. (I can always do it with a macro that spits out the \draw command).

@N.Virgo More or less, yes. It even draws a straight line if only \tikztostart is a node. But maybe this could be enhanced. Of course, this is just a rough idea.

what would be really cool is if one of the end points is a node then it only curves at the other end. I originally hoped to accomplish this with something like the only in from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609221/12461

@N.Virgo Maybe there are other approaches to this, but you can't just test \tikztostart like this, as it does not contain what you look for (and is not defined at that point in time anyways). But I currently have no better idea about how to do this.
